# Setting an onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am setting an on click listener and I was wondering if this was an ok way to do it? I see a lot of people define the onClickListener in line with the setOnClickListener but that seems really messy so I was wondering if I would run into any problems doing it this way down the road?

```
public class Login extends Activity {

protected Button login;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    login.setOnClickListener(myOnClick());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
    return true;
}

protected OnClickListener myOnClick() {
    OnClickListener v = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Do stuff
        }
    };

    return v;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you define it is your personal coding style choice. You can have the entire class implement the interface, do it inline, do it as you are doing or specify the method to be called via XML. The end result is more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep all your onclicklistener methods within one method you could implement the method. For this you do

> login.setOnClickListener(this);

And then

```
extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

And finally you will add the unimplemented methods. This will pass all your button clicks to the onclick method where you can use if/else or switch/case to assign whatever method.

Alternatively you can also define it in XML or use the method you've described.

However to go into the benefits and drawbacks: defining the onClick within xml can lead to problems with proguard. Personally I feel the easiest is using a switch and case within the onclicklistener, but if the method is a lot longer then it's nice to give it it's own method so to "hide" it away. If you however need common code to run after any button is pressed (for example a UI refresh) might be better to leave it to a switch and case or if/else

// Just to add for those wanting to use OnClick within xml and proguard

Add this:

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
   public void *(android.view.View); 
 }

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches for implementing `onClickListner` on the views. What you have used is also correct and will not create any problem to you. What i personally prefer is to let the Class implement `OnClickListener interface` and use switch case scenario inside the override onClick method .

e.g.

```
public class LoginExampleImplements extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    ...         

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

// Set Click Listener 


        btn1.setOnClickListener(this); 
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this); 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        switch(v.getId()){
           case R.id.btn1:
             // do stuff related btn1 click
             break;
           case R.id.btn2:
             // do stuff related btn2 click
             break;
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code style, still:

1. Want to use same method for a lot of buttons: let class implement listener interface, and use a switch on view id to find out which button clicked.
2. Really complex logic follows click: Have an inner/external class implement that listener.
3. Few lines, nothing special: do inline, the person reading you code need not go looking for a small piece of code.